# Mysql query null field replace with custom if statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case, inner-join

I have the below Mysql query doest quite work as expected yet. I am not a Mysql expert but basically what I am trying to do is for every AptStatus = 3 I have a Null field for Operatory.  Id like to convert that Null field to the Operatory name for each count of the location.  (hopefully that makes sense).

```
select Location, AptDate, IF(AptStatus = 3, '08:00:00', AptTime) AptTime, IF(AptStatus = 3, 540, AptLength) AptLength,AptStatus, OperatoryNum, Operatory
from rpt_officeschedules
where AptTime between '07:59:00' and '17:30:00' and AptDate between '2020-11-07' and '2020-11-08' and (Operatory LIKE '%NP%' or Operatory LIKE '%OPEN%'or Operatory is null )
order by Location, AptDate, OperatoryNum,AptTime, Operatory;
```

Sample Data

[image: Sample Data]

That location has these operators that come from the same table.

[image]

The expected results is this

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `join`:

```
select 
    o.location, 
    o.aptdate, 
    case when o.aptstatus = 3 then '08:00:00' else o.apttime   end as apttime, 
    case when o.aptstatus = 3 then 540        else o.aptlength end as aptlength,
    o.aptstatus, 
    o.operatory, 
    a.operatory as operatorynum
from rpt_officeschedules o
inner join apptwidget_operatorie a on a.location = o.location
where 
    o.apttime between '07:59:00' and '17:30:00' 
    and o.aptdate between '2020-11-07' and '2020-11-08' 
    and (o.operatory like '%np%' or o.operatory like '%open%' or o.operatory is null)
order by o.location, o.aptdate, o.operatorynum, o.apttime, o.operatory;
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention,  i only have one table unfortunately, I had it written previously somewhat as you have it it but I have to pull it from one time

Comment: @chewie: I don't get it. Your question shows two tables: the one that's in the query, `rpt_officeschedules`, and the one that's displayed afterwards in the questioapptwidget_operatorie , `apptwidget_operatorie`.

Comment: @chewie: the update on your question basically invalidates both answers that were posted - and it makes the question unclear (at least in my opinion...). You might want to ask *a new question*, providing proper sample data from the table and the correspoding desired results (as tabular text).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to cycle through the second table assigning the values in a round-robin fashion.  If so, you can use window functions:

```
select os.Location, os.AptDate, 
       (case when os.AptStatus = 3 then '08:00:00' else os.AptTime end) as AptTime,
       (case when os.AptStatus = 3 then 540 else os.AptLength end) as AptLength,
       os.AptStatus, os.OperatoryNum, os.Operatory
from (select os.*,
             row_number() over (partition by location order by atpdate) as seqnum
      from rpt_officeschedules os
      where os.AptTime between '07:59:00' and '17:30:00' and
            os.AptDate between '2020-11-07' and '2020-11-08' and
            (Operatory LIKE '%NP%' or Operatory LIKE '%OPEN%'or Operatory is null )
     ) os join
     (select aw.*, count(*) over (partition by location) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by location order by location) as seqnum
      from appwidget ap
     ) ap
     on os.location = ap.location and
        (os.seqnum - 1) % sp.cnt = ap.seqnum - 1
order by os.Location, os.AptDate, os.OperatoryNum, os.AptTime, os.Operatory;
```

Comment: [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by Location order by AptDate) as seqnum from rpt_officeschedule' at line 6

Comment: I updated my expected results, just realized it was wrong